# Variables are not visible in script Inspector window

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I started Unity a couple of days ago and I'm confused.

This is my current workspace:

[image]

This is what is should look like:

[image]

I should be able to fill in the variables but I can't.

Comment: Does the Board Manager contain any relevant code? It looks like either the introspection failed - or probably more likely that it is missing the code (or has unsaved code).

Comment: I have public variables but I still have the same error.

Comment: Can you show some code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. To show properties/variables in the inspector, they must be `public`, if they are not they won't appear.
2. You can also view `private fields` by attributing them as `[SerializeField]`.
3. To view custom classes in the inspector, you should mark them as `[Serializable]`.
4. To hide public variables from inspector, use `[HideInInspector]` or  `[System.NonSerialized]` attribute.

Here is a sample:

```
public class SomePerson : MonoBehaviour 
{
    //This field gets serialized because it is public.
    public string name = "John";

    //This field does not get serialized because it is private.
    private int age = 40;

    //This field gets serialized even though it is private
    //because it has the SerializeField attribute applied.
    [SerializeField]
    private bool hasHealthPotion = true;

    // This will be displayed in the inspector because the class has Serialized attribute.
    public SomeCustomClass somCustomClassInstance;

    // This will not be shown in inspector even if it is public.
    [HideInInspector]
    public bool hiddenBool;    

    // Same with this one.
    [System.NonSerialized]
    public int nonSerializedVariable = 5;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class SomeCustomClass
{
    public string someProperty;
}
```

Comment: I have public variables but I still have the same error. :(

Comment: What is the error?? please post your script along with question

Comment: what do you mean? @khawar

Comment: @ZakTheHat i mean where is code which you are using in that script. can you post here?